# implement query language on python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm looking for a way to expose filtering functionality at my workplace to other developers and optionally customers.

## Problem

i want to implement a simple query language over my data (python dicts) based on user defined filters exposed to my other developers and later on to our customers.

- the language should be simple enough to be used by non-developers
- safe enough to avoid remote code execution on my servers
- expressive enough to query data like the below example

Exposing SQL interface over my dict / json data would be great (I prefer not to setup server)

## Example Scenario

```
db = [
  {'first': 'john', 'last': 'doe', 'likes': ['cookies', 'http']},
  {'first': 'jane', 'last': 'doe', 'likes': ['cookies', 'donuts']},
  {'first': 'danny', 'last': 'foo', 'likes': ['http', 'donuts']},
]

query = '(first == "john" or last == "doe") and likes contains "cookies"'
results = run_query(db, query)
```

this should return (in results):

```
[
  {'first': 'john', 'last': 'doe', 'likes': ['cookies', 'http']},
  {'first': 'jane', 'last': 'doe', 'likes': ['cookies', 'donuts']},
]
```

**note:** i do not mind changing the operator names, e.g. `or -> OR` `contains -> inside` or anything else as long as it is human readable and keeps the same expressiveness of the language

## Solutions I Tried

#### DSL

I looked at some DSL libraries like [PLY](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply) but they seems to me too complex and involves some magic to get things done (not really sure where to start and if its worth it)

#### Plugins

didnt find any plugin system to expose a sandboxed functionality for my users (i.e. safer eval)

#### JSON Query Packages

I looked at [TinyDB](http://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and others that implement some sort of SQL over json but couldn't find something that work without alot of customizations.
I also looked at [pandasql](https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/) which seems good overall but unmaintained library :(

there is a lucene package parser - [luqum](https://github.com/jurismarches/luqum) based on `PLY` but its different from my syntax tree (they have more methods) and the lib is not really maintained, (I do consider manipulating this lib a bit to get what i want)

#### SQLite

use SQLiteDB to load all my data (in memory or not) and then run SQL queries over it. didnt test it but this should be pretty straightforward with the downside of loading my whole data into SQL just to run the data on which i prefer not to do.

**I am open to suggestions or even on how to improve the above solution to make this work**

Comment: Probably using `pandas` already can give you a lot of functionality, especially the `DataFrame.query(..)` part.

Comment: thanks @WillemVanOnsem but can i pass a query string to it? if not and I should parse the query string before passing to the `df.query(..)` do you have any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Yes, it does not work however for membership checks (`contains`, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before using PLY for text based queries, I would build-up the core language from regular Python classes like this:

```
class Match:
    def __init__(self, **target):
        [[self.key, self.value]] = target.items()
    def __call__(self, obj):
        return self.key in obj and self.value == obj[self.key]

class Contains:        
    def __init__(self, **target):
        [[self.key, self.value]] = target.items()
    def __call__(self, obj):
        return self.key in obj and self.value in obj[self.key]        

class Or:
    def __init__(self, *predicates):
        self.predicates = predicates
    def __call__(self, record):
        return any(predicate(record) for predicate in self.predicates)

class And:
    def __init__(self, *predicates):
        self.predicates = predicates
    def __call__(self, record):
        return all(predicate(record) for predicate in self.predicates)

def run_query(db, query):
    return filter(query, db)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    db = [
      {'first': 'john', 'last': 'doe', 'likes': ['cookies', 'http']},
      {'first': 'jane', 'last': 'doe', 'likes': ['cookies', 'donuts']},
      {'first': 'danny', 'last': 'foo', 'likes': ['http', 'donuts']},
    ]
    query = And(Or(Match(first='john'), Match(last='doe')), Contains(likes='cookies'))
    for result in run_query(db, query):
        print(result)
```

This outputs:

```
{'first': 'john', 'last': 'doe', 'likes': ['cookies', 'http']}
{'first': 'jane', 'last': 'doe', 'likes': ['cookies', 'donuts']}
```

Comment: thanks @Raymond Hettinger for the elegant & pythonic solution.
actually i ended up using PLY which worked great (required some magic on some cases). simple example: hand.name = 'full-house'

Answer (score 0):

SQL is widely known and commonly requested by end users. I know of a couple of options which makes this possible in python. They rely on external libraries, but are well supported.

**Small data solution**

Input dictionary into a `pd.DataFrame`, e.g. see [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html). Then query via [`pandasql`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandasql) library. It seems you've tried this already, but I mention it as (in my experience) it does what it says.

**Big data solution**

Save your data in HDF5 format. `pandas` dataframes and `numpy` arrays can be easily stored in HDF5 format via [`h5py`](http://www.h5py.org/) library. Then use [`HDFql`](http://www.hdfql.com/) library to query the HDF5 file.

Comment: thanks but I prefer not to use pandasql as it is unmaintained. I might implement a syntax using PLY